# Final Fantasy VII - Best way to defeat Ruby and Emerald Weapons

Tags: final-fantasy-7

I have all the Materias (almost mastered, thus I'm close to some Master Materias), and the characters (Cloud, Tifa and Barret) are respectively level 88, 87 and 88.

I'm thinking about the W-Summon/KOTR/Mime/Mime method, but I'm not so sure about... I never fought Ruby nor Emerald weapon.

Suggestions?

Comment: Do you want general tips or a specific list of instructions?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**General Tips**:
Equip party members with Mystile Armor (Definitely if you dont plan on using Hades against Ruby)
Use Big Guard Enemy Skill (BG)
Final Attack-Phoenix on your tankest (most HP) character
Preferably link KOTR with mp/hp absorb and/or mp turbo. You can also link a Master Summon to one of these for same effect.
If either of the weapons use Status effects (I believe Rubys claws can) than Ribbon is an amazing accessory to equip

**Ruby Trick:** Go into battle with 2 characters dead, Ruby will stick its claws into the ground, you can then revive or summon Phoenix (to revive)
and have 3 chars for this fight

**Note:** Hades (Summon) / Dazers (Item) can paralyze Ruby (May want to try a w-summon Hades/KOTR for a safer but longer Ruby Battle)
**Note:** Having Underwater materia equipped gets rid of timer on Emerald
**Note:** Gravity will do 9999 dmg to Emerald (Quad Magic+hp/mp absorb linked can be a solid assault) <- Atleast until Emerald is VERY close to dead
**Note:** Aire tam (notice, materia backwords) Storm will do damage depending on how many materia your character has (1111 x # of materia equipped iirc) <- I usually just
counter(ignore) this with final attack + phoenix.
**Note:** You can duplicate Megalixirs with the W-Item trick if you want.
**Note:** If you link the same materia to separate support (blue) materia, all the effects linked will be activated in battle.

Example of final note: You have 2 Fire Materias, one linked with HP Absorb, the other with All, when you cast fire it will hit all enemies AND absorb HP.
This can also be done with the Master Magic/Master Summon Materia. A common trick is to link Master Summon with HP Absorb and KOTR summon with MP Turbo, giving a max damage KOTR where each hit absorbs HP

**For Emerald:**
Open with BG
Cast W-summon KOTR (preferably linked with hp/mp absorb)
Then
Mime until you die
FA+Phoenix will revive you
recast BG
recast W-summon+KOTR
Repeat

OR

Mime until you are close to dead
use a megalixir
recast BG
recast W-summon+KOTR
Repeat

Alternatively, you can W-magic a quadra magic demi (with hp/mp absorb) and when it stops doing 9999 dmg use all your limit breaks to finish it.
Again megalixir is your best bet when weak.

**For Ruby:**
Go into battle with 2 chars dead, and the third with FA+Phoenix.
When Ruby puts claws into ground, revive team.
Cast BG
W-Summon KOTRx2 or Hades+KOTR (RECOMMENDED)
Mime until you are near dead
Megalixir
Recast BG
Now W-Summon
Mime

If this Ruby strategy does not work for you i can edit with a separate one.

Remember both these monsters have insane HP so these battles will take a while, even with the ridiculousness that is KOTR.

I also prefer to equip Scimitar and Apocalypse because Ruby and Emerald give insane AP (50 000 iirc) And these are the only 2 weapons with Triple Growth slots
Hope this helps, Cheers

Comment: "Gravity will do 9999 dmg to Emerald (Quad Magic+hp/mp absorb linked can be a solid assault)". How do you link these Materia?

Comment: Basically, on the same character if you have a gravity linked with quad magic, and a separate gravity linked with hp absorb, and a separate gravity linked with mp absorb, then when you cast demi, it will cast 4x with hp/mp aborb effects. If you have a w-magic, you will be able to cast this demi twice, for 8x 9999 dmg with each healing your hp/mp. Adding note to my answer

Comment: WOW! I didn't know I could link Materia in that way! It works with Summons too?

Comment: Yes, Summons and Magic and even certain Command Materia. You can also do this with the Master materia of these 3 as well.

Comment: Truly droolin'...

Comment: Another note is that if you dont do any actions in between, you can mime a characters limit break (Cloud limits, no one else does anything...Cloud uses mime->Second limit). Cool trick especially useful for finishing off Emerald in the gravity method, or when not using Ruby trick against Ruby

Comment: Ahahah, just tried the gravity trick (gravity-mp turbo, gravity-quadra magic, w-magic) with 8 Demi casted...on a Master Tonberry! :D I gave him 5555x8 and know what? He thanks me with "Everyone's Grudge"!

Comment: Haha yeah, the only time i recommend fighting Master Tonberries is when you are trying to morph them!! painful fight with little reward otherwise

Comment: Now, does that materia linkage trick work regardless of the level of materia used? Say I have a master gravity linked... can I use 2 more fresh-off-the-shelf gravity-s and still get the same desired effect? Or do they need to be mastered too?

Comment: The effects are linked to the skill that is unlocked on the materia. So in your case, demi would have all the effects, demi 2/3 would only have the one linked with the master gravity (this is sufficient for emerald, since demi will be strong enough to do 9999 for long enough, afterwards one KOTR or few limits will finish it). For summons, level does not matter.

Comment: There are lots and lots of good materia combos, but this guide lists lots of good ones: http://www.gamefaqs.com/ps/197341-final-fantasy-vii/faqs/2388

Answer (score 3):

A very cheap strategy is to use the [Lucky 7s](http://strategywiki.org/wiki/Final_Fantasy_VII/Status_Effects#Lucky_Sevens) status.

One way to force it is to go for 7677 HP before the battle, then just as it starts use a potion to get 7777 HP and Lucky 7s status. If I'm not mistaken you hit something like 64 times, dealing 7777 damage per hit.

Comment: baxterjn actually has a nifty Lucky 7s guide: http://www.gamefaqs.com/ps/197341-final-fantasy-vii/faqs/60479

Comment: Easiest way to do this vs Ruby is to exploit Aire Tam. Have a char on 9999 HP with 2 Materia equipped. Then when Ruby casts Aire Tam, it does 2222 damage leaving you on 7777 which triggers lucky7s!

Answer (score 1):

I always used cloud, barret, and cid.
I had attack x4 on all of them. this did 40k damage per attack. 4x better than most other spells or attacks. Use limits as much as possible, but always prioritize heals.

Pair the final attack with a mastered Pheonix summon. I've never used this but I've heard it works like a charm.

If you are aware how to duplicate megalixers, this helps a lot. If you aren't a fan of doing it that way. it's just harder, but cure3's with all are handy too.